# Error in sql query that generates a new column

Tags: sql

I have this query that has a column 'test' and the 'test' column should show a different message depending on the salary and job_id. For example, if the salary is '1000' for the job_id 'IT_PROG' it should show 'below' because in the hr.jobs table the min salary for 'IT_PROG' is 4200.

```
select 
first_name,
salary,
min(salary) as min_salary,
max(salary) as max_salary,
CASE WHEN salary < min_salary THEN 
                  'Below max' 
              WHEN salary > max_salary THEN 
                  'Above max'     
              WHEN salary BETWEEN min_salary AND max_salary THEN 
                  'Between'                                 
          END as Test


from hr.employees

 where salary = 1000 and hr.employees.job_id  = 'IT_PROG';
```

Comment: You need a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You can't have salary both as argument to set function and not. Chose one of them.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to calculate the values:

```
select e.first_name, e.salary, m.min_salary, m.max_salary,
       (case when e.salary < m.min_salary then 'Below max' 
             when e.salary > m.max_salary then 'Above max'     
             else 'Between'                                 
        end) as Test
from hr.employees e cross join
     (select min(salary) as min_salary, max(salary) as max_salary
      from hr.employees
     ) m
where e.salary = 1000 and e.job_id = 'IT_PROG';
```

If you could get the logic in your query to work, it would apply the `where` filtering logic to the `min()` and `max()` calculations -- and the only value for `test` would be `'between'`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server you could declare the salary manually:

```
DECLARE @min_salary as int 
SET @min_salary = 4200
DECLARE @max_salary as int 
SET @max_salary = 10000

select 
first_name,
salary,
CASE WHEN salary < @min_salary THEN 
                  'Below max' 
              WHEN salary > @max_salary THEN 
                  'Above max'     
              WHEN salary BETWEEN @min_salary AND @max_salary THEN 
                  'Between'                                 
          END as Test


from hr.employees

 where salary = 1000 and hr.employees.job_id  = 'IT_PROG';
```

Comment: How do you know Oscar is using SQL Server?